# How to set Azure Sql Service Tier when creating DB via EF Core EnsureCreated?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database

When I use the Entity Framework Core EnsureCreated to automatically generate my Azure Sql Database it sets the service tier of the database to be an expensive tier by default.

How do I force the database to be created using the Basic service tier?

I found an example for but it doesn't apply to EF for .NET Core.

Comment: It will be fixed/available in 3.1, in the mean time you can use raw ADO.NET

Comment: Thanks  @ErikEJ have you seen any doco on this? Do you know what the solution will be in 3.1?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts? I've scoured the internet and have found no info around this :(

Answer (score 2):

You can use code like this with EF Core 3.1 to configure your Azure SQL database:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
            modelBuilder.HasDatabaseMaxSize("2 GB");

            modelBuilder.HasServiceTier("BusinessCritical");

            modelBuilder.HasPerformanceLevel("BC_Gen4_1");
}
```

(Some changes were made from 3.0: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/pull/18544/files#diff-3eb328f3c708536a3be15d81c1d023e2L128 )

Comment: Thanks @ErikEJ I spent all day upgrading my code to use EF Core 3.1 and these options on the ModelBuilder. When the Database is created via EnsureCreatedAsync it works. However, the service tier is still not set when using MigrateAsync. Unfortunately I haven't been able to find any doco why this is the case. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: No idea. Maybe ask in EF Core GitHub repo